# Get the sum of all the rows in each records

Tags: php, mysql

Help me guys. I have a problem on how to sum all records of students
in each rows. this is my php code

```
 while ($students = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$students['id']}<input type='hidden' name='id[$i]' value='{$students['id']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td>{$students['fld_name']}</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz1[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz1']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz2[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz2']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz3[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz3']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz4[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz4']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz5[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz5']}' /></td>";
    echo '<td> total here </td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    ++$i;
}
```

This is my output

[image]

Comment: `$var1 + $var2 + ...`?

Comment: so you want to get total right

Comment: yes i want to get the total

Comment: You want total of Quiz 1, Quiz 2, Quiz 3, Quiz 4 and Quiz 5.. ?

Comment: yes i want to total all quiz

Answer (score 2):

you can just add all values and store it in one variable and show it in last column. refer below,

```
while ($students = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $total = $students['fld_quiz1'] + $students['fld_quiz2'] + $students['fld_quiz3'] + $students['fld_quiz4'] + $students['fld_quiz5'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$students['id']}<input type='hidden' name='id[$i]' value='{$students['id']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td>{$students['fld_name']}</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz1[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz1']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz2[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz2']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz3[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz3']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz4[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz4']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz5[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz5']}' /></td>";
    echo '<td>'.$total.'</td>';// Show it here
    echo '</tr>';

    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: Interesting that this (and the other answer) got up votes while the previous answer (now removed) got a down vote for doing the exact same thing. However, this does work :-)

Comment: Sorry, which answer here removed? i didn't see

Comment: There was an answer earlier, doing this exact same thing. For some reason, it got a down vote after 10 seconds and the poster removed it. However, it doesn't effect that this does what the OP wants :-)

Comment: thanks its work :-) how about i want to add remarks in each quiz

Comment: yes, above each columns of quiz1, quiz2, quiz3, quiz4, and quiz5 i will put the textbox that let the user input their desired remarks

Comment: @ArnoldLagbas - That's another issue. If this answer solved the original question, you should accept it. If you have other issues, post a new question.

Comment: I'm so sorry i am just a beginner here, I'm not aware of the rules that I cannot post another questions. thank you

Answer (score 2):

`$total` will make a sum of all the quiz like 1 to 5 and print that variable to last `td` as below

```
while ($students = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $total = ($students['fld_quiz1'] + $students['fld_quiz2'] + $students['fld_quiz3'] + $students['fld_quiz4'] + $students['fld_quiz5']);

    //if marks are from 100 then
    $avg = ($total * 100) / 500;

    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$students['id']}<input type='hidden' name='id[$i]' value='{$students['id']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td>{$students['fld_name']}</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz1[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz1']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz2[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz2']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz3[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz3']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz4[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz4']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='5' name='fld_quiz5[$i]' value='{$students['fld_quiz5']}' /></td>";
    echo '<td> ' .$total. ' </td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: $total = ($students['fld_quiz1'] + $students['fld_quiz2'] + $students['fld_quiz3'] + $students['fld_quiz4'] + $students['fld_quiz5']) / 5;

Comment: the marks are from 100 if so then, I have updated my ans?

Comment: thanks its work :-) i have no remarks yet, i want to have a remarks that the user will input his choice